# How to run single testcase with Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, android-testing

According to official documentation function *MonkeyDevice.instrument(className, args)* is perfectly suitable for this task.

As I understand this should be done like this:

```
device.instrument('my.package.name/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner', {'class':'my.package.name.SingleTest'})
```

However it still launches all test-cases. Is it bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a chimpchat bug.
I've just uploaded a [path](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/37560) that fixes the problem.
Once applied, you will be able to run all the tests in a class by using the same syntax you are using.

If you want to give it a try before the patch is merged you can

1. download android source
2. cherry pick patch 37560
3. set the environment (build/envsetup.sh)
4. lunch
5. make chimpchat
6. make monkeyrunner

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
device.shell('am instrument -w -e class my.package.name.SingleTest my.package.name/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner')
```

For some reason, device.instrument() way doesn't work for me even with latest sdk 20.0.1 and platform 14.